# Comparison operator between asynchronous functions

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have two asynchronous function which returns boolean value after doing some complex calculations as below.

Function 1:

```
public Task<bool> function1()
{   
      //do some calculation and gives boolean value
      return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Function 2:

```
public Task<bool> function2()
{   
      //do some calculation and gives boolean value
      return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

And I want to use comparison operator between these two functions as below.

```
public async Task<bool> function2()
{   
     return await function1() && await function2();
}
```

Is this a good approach to use comparison operator (and, or) between two asynchronous function. If not how can we do this in a better way?

Comment: except that in your code sample you're not actually _calling_ the methods (because you lack the parentheses), there's nothing _wrong_ about this. as for "good" - depends on what you define as _good_. which is opinion-based. my opinion on that matter is: does it work? is it understandable? is it maintainable?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to ask. It's not clear why you have `Task`-returning methods which aren't actually asynchronous, for example. Given that you do, it's not clear what your concern is.

Comment: What is the point of comparing 2 methods? What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you mean you want to compare *the result* from 2 different methods instead given the same input.

Comment: Assuming you actually call the functions, `await function1() && await function2()` compares the *results*, not the functions. Comparing two functions (actually, delegates) makes no sense - they're always different.

Comment: Yes, I want to compare the results from these functions. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways how to call this. The first one is the one that you presented:

```
public async Task<bool> function2()
{   
   return await function1() && await function2();
}
```

This means: `function1()` is executed, and when it's finished, then `function2()` is executed. But your method is `async`, so maybe you want to execute them concurrently? In that case, you have to call it the following way:

```
public async Task<bool> function2()
    {   
       var result1 = function1();
       var result2 = function2();
       return await result1 && await result2;
    }
```